# Get the output of date without "comma" using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have following data in json file

`{ "date": "Tue, 27 Jun 2017 18:06:02 +0530"}`

I want to get the output of date without comma, so that I can put it to CSV file without any issues.

I want output like `Tue 27 Jun 2017 18:06:02 +0530`

Thanks in advance.

and my code goes like this:

```
 var Decision = 'Bounce';
     document.write("<br><br><strong>Bounced Data</strong><br>");
     document.write("Date"+'<br>');
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length ; i++){
  if (obj[i].Message.notificationType == Decision){
      document.write(obj[i].Message.mail.commonHeaders.date+','+"<br>");      
  }  
}
```

so,for date ill get o/p like this:"Tue, 27 Jun 2017 18:06:02 +053"....when i put output to csv it comes in two fields....

Comment: can you add some code ?

Comment: FYI, the CSV format allows commas in values.

Comment: "so that I can put it to CSV file without any issues" — Sounds like the issues are caused by a poor quality CVS generator.

Comment: No, I don't think we get your point. Why mangle data and not just fix the CSV generator?

Comment: yes we can,this is a bit of my work in project,still theres an extension for this to approach...tnq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourObject.date.replace(/,/,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var Decision = 'Delivery';
             document.write("<br><br><strong>Delivered Data</strong><br>");
             document.write("Date"+'<br>');
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length ; i++){
          if (obj[i].Message.notificationType == Decision){
              document.write(obj[i].Message.mail.commonHeaders.date.replace(/,/,'')+','+"<br>");

          }

        }
-------------------------------
"date.replace(/,/,'')"
output:Tue 27 Jun 2017 18:06:02 +0530
this part succeded in removing comma at output of date,thanks a lot for every participant.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for parsing date in a safe way.

```js
var time = 'Tue,27 Jun 2017 18:06:02 +0530';
var parsed = moment.parseZone(time, 'ddd,D MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z');
var newTime = parsed.format('ddd D MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ');
console.log(newTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is that really necessary when `.replace(',','')` will do it just fine?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol This solution is much universal and safer for parsing date and time. e.g. errors won't be thrown if the date string was not in current format when using regex replacing, but moment.js will.

Answer (score -1):

This code would be helpful to you:

```
var str = "Tue, 27 Jun 2017 18:06:02 +0530"; 
str.replace(",", "");
```

Here I used string for example but you can use like

```
obj.data.replace(",", "");
```